# Is it possible to remove the link to the Support-a-Creator feature?

Tags: technical-issues, fortnite-battle-royale

A few days ago, I entered a Creator ID for the Fortnite Share the Love event and bought an item to get the free wrap in the 7.40 patch update.

Now, I don't want to support a creator anymore. I tried blanking out the creator name, then submit but it was telling me "Connection error. Please try again later" on Switch and PC.

Looking into the Support-a-Creator FAQ, I cannot find any information concerning removing the supported creator. Changing the supported creator works just fine. Do I really have to keep supporting a creator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the information on [EpicGames](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/news/support-a-creator) Support-A-Creator page, the support will last 14 days. After the the period is up, you will be able to choose either a previous/new player to support or (if I am interpreting it correctly) be free from  supporting players until you choose to support again.

> You can change the Creator you support at any time. Your support for a Creator lasts 14 days. After that, you can reselect your Creator or choose a new one at any time.

Comment: Oh. So it does expire by itself. I certainly did miss this information. I will see if this works in about week then, but I believe your interpretation is correct. I will leave this open until I can attest this is right.

Comment: @Ekinox Sounds good! This is the only information I could find regarding support-a-creator expiring. Hopefully somebody else can back this up without having to wait until it does expire

Comment: This is the correct answer. The support feature goes away after some time while not changing the creator. I just was not patient enough! :) answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

So no, you cannot change your support a creator at any time. You can change it 2 weeks later, meaning that any purchase you make in those 2 weeks is supporting said creator. Meaning fortnite has removed your freedom of choice in unsupporting creators, yet people still advertise it as if the player does in fact have freedom of choice and can instantly remove said creator code, which is simply not true.